# Floor function returning wrong values

Tags: r

Can someone explain me this weird behavior in R? Why isn't the first expression evaluated to 57?

```
> floor(0.57*100)
[1] 56
> floor(0.56*100)
[1] 56
```

R version 3.4.1

Comment: `sprintf("%.54f",0.57)` is `0.5699999999999999511501869164931...`

Comment: @thelatemail 0.57*100 = 57

Comment: @Headpoint - no, no it doesn't. Not when computing and floating point numbers are involved - see the duplicate question.

Comment: @thelatemail I agree it is not quite 57. But certainly close to 57 than 56!

Comment: @Headpoint - but they're not rounding, they're flooring. Doesn't matter how close it is to 57 if it doesn't quite reach it.

Comment: So what is the best way to get 57 out of floor(0.57*100)?  ._.

Comment: @thelatemail. I see. I was thinking rounding for some reason.